# Program having low cache and main memory hit

Tags: caching, memory, io, operating-system

In a question, prof asked

**"Think of an application that would have a very low cache and main memory hit rate?"**

Should I think of a program with high I/O, like database related things etc or should I think programs with to many different method calls or something else?

I'm a bit confused because cache keeps data and corresponding memory addresses,right?

If I'm reading a file from disk, will I use cache for a reason?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: there's many caches in a PC. ram cache, L3, L2, L1 caches in the CPU. you'd need to be more specific.

Comment: Assume there is one layer of cache(L1 only) and memory and disk in the machine.